# .NET 7 Error CS0118 'UserService' is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I have my services under a folder called `Services` in the project and I have grouped the User related parts in a folder called `UserService`. And under that folder, I have an Interface called `IUserService.cs` and a class called `UserService.cs` which contain basic user authentication methods.

Here is a picture of the folder structure:

[image: Here is a picture of the folder structure]

To register this User service to dependency injection I have used an extension method class called `RegisterServices.cs`.

And this is the error I get when i try to register the user service using the below code: `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS0118  'UserService' is a namespace but is used like a type    Infinium.API    D:\Infinium Projects\Infinium\Infinium.API\Services\ServiceRegister.cs  16  Active`

Below is the code of `RegisterServices.cs`

```
using Infinium.API.Authorization;
using Infinium.API.DataManager;
using Infinium.API.Services.UserService;

namespace Infinium.API.Services
{
    public static class ServiceRegister
    {
        public static void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // vNext DB
            services.AddSingleton<IDataAccessor, DataAccessor>();

            //services.Configure<AppSettings>(getser)
            services.AddScoped<IJwtUtils, JwtUtils>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

        }
    }
}
```

I have added the RegisterServices extension method class to `Program.cs` as follows;

```
using Infinium.API.Authorization;
using Infinium.API.Helpers;
using Infinium.API.Services;
using MaxRAV.API.Helpers;
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowedCorsOrigins",
builder =>
{
    builder
.SetIsOriginAllowed((_) => true)
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowCredentials();
});
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// configure strongly typed settings object
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

builder.Services.RegisterServices();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341") // comment if not configired
    );

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("AllowedCorsOrigins");


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// global error handler
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

// custom jwt auth middleware
app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The same code used to work with .NET 5 and in .NET 6 sometimes this error was thrown. I assume that the folder name conflicts with the class name, but I am not sure why it doesn't happen all the time.
Maybe the solution is to rename the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this, e.g. use fully qualified type names, like

```
services.AddScoped<Infinium.API.Services.UserService.IUserService, 
                   Infinium.API.Services.UserService.UserService>();
```

Namespace names conflicting with class names sometimes can cause this kind of issues.

Another idea would be to maintain a separation between these, so that if your namespace ends with `UserService`, the class has a different name. An advice would be to have the namespace ending with a plural version of whatever you have, like

```
Infinium.API.Services.UserServices
```

and the class name in the namespace is

```
UserService
```

Alternatively, you can use the `typeof` operator to specify the type of the `UserService` class, like below

```
public static class RegisterServices
{
    public static void AddUserService(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, typeof(UserService)>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Zychla for your answer. I thought of pluralizing the namespace, as it is easier than using the full path. Still not sure why IntelliSense doesn't tag this name conflict always as an issue. And what changed since .NET 5?

Comment: It's not a new issue, I'd even suspect .NET7 hasn't changed anything. Most of your apps are still on 4.7.2 and we ocasionally bump into this. Pluralizing is the most preferred way of resolving this.